# Stopped cadlag submartingale is integrable

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, martingales, stopping-times, uniform-integrability

I'm trying to understand, why a stopped submartingale is again a submartingale. In the lecture notes to my lecture this is just stated as a corollary of Doob's Optional Sampling Theorem but I don't see why the stopped submartingale is necessarily integrable. More explicitely, I'm trying to prove:

Let $X$ be a (continuous time) cadlag submartingale, $T$ a stopping time, $t\geq 0$.

Then, $\mathbb E \left|X^T_t\right|=\mathbb E\left|X_{\min\{T,t\}}\right|<\infty$.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: I can show that a stopped cadlag martingale is integrable by applying Doob's optional sampling to the martingales absolute value but don't know how to proceed for submartingales :/

Comment: I thought this too at first but sadly it is false. The absolute value of a submartingale is not necessarily a submartingale.